# c++ value elision and destructors?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a file handling class, and one of the features I'd like it to have is "excursions" where you temporarily seek to part of the file and then seek back.  I'd like this to be done automatically.  The idea is I'd have code like the following in my file class:

```
struct File {
    ... 
    struct Excursion { 
         Excursion(File& file, off64_t new_off) 
             : pi_(make_shared<impl>(file, new_off)) {}

    private:
         struct impl { 
             impl(File& file, off64_t new_off)
                 : file(file), off(file.tell()) {
                 file.seek(new_off);
             }

             ~impl() { 
                  file.seek(off);
             }

             File &file;
             off64_t off;
         };

         shared_ptr<impl> pi_;
    };

    Excursion excursion(off64_t off) { 
        return Excursion(*this, off);
    }
};
```

Then I could start an excursion with something like:

```
file.excursion(512);
```

Which would return an Excursion object that just holds a reference to the file and the current offset.  When this object goes out of scope, it restores the file offset automatically.  This makes it very nice for code that has to jump over the file to parse it.

My question is, if I return that Excursion object from file.excursion() and don't assign it to anything, is C++ allowed to elide the value altogether and not call the destructor?

Edit:

Per below, Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000 is correct, the destructor is not elided.  *However*, executing an excursion as shown above returns an object, which is immediately destructed as it's not assigned to anything.

Reading [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime), since it's a temporary value that's returned from that function evaluation, the object is destroyed as the last step in evaluating the expression where it's created.  Thus, it does *not* persist until the end of the enclosing scope.  So this technique can't work without assigning the excursion object to a variable at the higher scope.

This would work:

```
Excursion ex = file.excursion(512);
```

But it's a matter of opinion whether having to have a dummy variable lying around is the right thing.

Comment: check the "as if" rule.

Comment: Can you clarify your usage? You mean like `Excursion foo() { return file.excursion(512); }`?

Comment: "is C++ allowed to elide the value altogether and not call the destructor?" are you asking if compiler allowed not to call destructor for created object, or it is allowed not to create object at all?

Comment: No, destructors cannot generally be omitted if you requested one. The only thing that can be omitted even if it has side effects are copies (and the adherent destructions of the intermediates, of course).

Comment: if this could happen any function that returns smart pointer can lead to a memory leak, strange question

Comment: @Barry  yes but I won't ever assign Excursion to anything...

Comment: @slava Difference being that I'm not assigning the instance to anything.  I'm curious if C++ still has to create the object and destroy it in that case, or if it can see that it's never used and not create the object in the first place...

Comment: @gct there is no difference, if a function returns smart pointer and somebody ignores result that will it lead to a memory leak?

Comment: @Slava not if the compiler elides the creation of the value altogether...

Comment: @gct how can you imagine that? It will skip whole statement with new? Ignore call to `make_shared()` or something like that? And all based on if result is used or not? Huh

Comment: @Slava I'm not calling new, I build an Excursion object and return it by value.  If it was an int I'm pretty sure that a lot of the time C++ could just elide the function call altogether, I'm curious if that can happen for more complex types...

Comment: @gct you build an object and return it, and based on that if result is used you worry if compiler is allowed not to create object? This should be your question, but answer is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it cannot ignore the destructor.

The compiler can do the optimization and remove part of the code only in case it finds out it doesn't have any effect. This is clearly not the case here as you call another method from the destructor which influences global state of some other object.

Comment: True indeed. Only if the optimiser was smart enough to figure out that the entire construction+destrution pair is a no-op, it could remove it all.

Comment: In fact, it can optimize out code which have some side effects - in copy elision

Comment: @stryku: Copy elision is a special case that was specifically pointed out in the standard. In the general case it can not remove code that has side affects.